# Autofac resolving named service incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, autofac

I am using AutoFac for dependency injection and I have the following code in the `global.asax` file.

```
builder.RegisterType<GenderMapper>()
    .As<ICodeMapper>().Named<ICodeMapper>(ValueSets.Gender.ToString());

builder.RegisterType<LanguageMapper>()
    .As<ICodeMapper>().Named<ICodeMapper>(ValueSets.Language.ToString());

builder.RegisterType<MaritalStatusMapper>()
    .As<ICodeMapper>().Named<ICodeMapper>(ValueSets.MaritalStatus.ToString());

builder.RegisterType<RelationshipMapper>()
    .As<ICodeMapper>().Named<ICodeMapper>(ValueSets.Relationship.ToString());

builder.Register<Antlr.Runtime.Misc.Func<string, ICodeMapper>>(c =>
{
    var componentContext = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
    return (roleName) =>
    {
        var codeMapper = componentContext.ResolveNamed<ICodeMapper>(roleName);
        return codeMapper;
    };
});
```

Where `ValueSets` is an enum. I resolve the services like so:

```
var codeMapper = _codeMapperFactory(mapperInstanceName);
```

Where `_codeMapperFactory` implements `ICodeMapper` and is the base abstract class for the 4 mappers registered above.

The problem is that, whatever be the value of `mapperInstanceName` be, I am always getting the mapper registered last (ie. `RelationshipMapper`).

When I debug, the costructor being called is of `RelationshipMapper` whatever be the value of the argument passed to the factory.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here and may require some back and forth discussion because there's not really enough info, but I'm a little short on time and would like to get you an answer to help you. I may or may not be able to make it back here so if my answer doesn't work it'd be better if you update your question with additional info rather than comment and sit and wait for me.

So.

I see that you've registered the mappers *both* as unnamed *and* named implementations of `ICodeMapper`. I also see that `RelationshipMapper` is the last one in, which means if you resolved an *unnamed* implementation that's the one you'd get.

```
// You'd get RelationshipMapper
container.Resolve<ICodeMapper>();
```

I also see that there's an `Antlr.Runtime.Misc.Func<string, ICodeMapper>` being registered. I don't know what that type is, but I can see high potential for it to conflict with `System.Func<string, ICodeMapper>`.

Autofac handles `System.Func` so if that's being called, you'd get an *unnamed* instance.

```
// You'd get RelationshipMapper
var f = container.Resolve<Func<ICodeMapper>>();
f();
```

Here's what I'd check:

- Make sure you can manually resolve your named mappers, just to ensure that works.
- Make sure you're resolving the Antlr `Func` and not `System.Func`.
- Try removing the `As<ICodeMapper>` and only use `Named<ICodeMapper>` if you're not resolving any unnamed types. You may start getting an exception and that may help you further troubleshoot. Like if Autofac throws an exception about no `ICodeMapper` being registered, you'll know it's not resolving *named* things, it's trying to resolve *unnamed* things.
- Throw an exception from your Antlr `Func` instead of calling `componentContext.ResolveNamed`. See if that ever actually gets hit. (I have bad luck setting breakpoints in those generated functions-from-functions. You could also try a breakpoint in there.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was resolving `System.Func` instead of `Antlr.Func`. Thanks a lot for the answer.